# Windows 8 - How do I sign in to Calendar with my Microsoft account?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-account, windows-8-calendar-app

I first opened calendar in Windows 8 and it asked me to sign-in my Microsoft account. I tried a couple times but it said wrong password. Therefore, I clicked cancel. How can I try again now? Is there no way now for me to sign-in and reap whatever benefits that brings to me? I am using Windows 8 Enterprise Evaluation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. Microsoft seems to be hiding even app settings into the settings charm in the charms bar. To access the accounts interface: go to the charms bar. click settings. click account. You may now make any account related changes.

Answer (score 2):

From the Start menu do a search for users.  make sure you search under "Settings" click on the USERS result which should take you to the PC Settings.  from here you can setup and link your accounts this is where it pulls your calendar info from not the calendar app itself if that makes sense.

Comment: ok thanks. i was just wondering if there was an interface for adding only calendars instead of a system wide account that affects several apps such as mail and contacts.